# Extracting time from a line in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

I got log entries like:

```
2013-01-09 06:13:51,464 DEBUG module 159 Djang...
```

What is the shortest (best) way to extract the date from this string?

Comment: You asked a question, answered it moments after asking, and then voted to close it? Sounds like you're just farming reputation with duplicate questions/answers.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic, I used the "answer your own question, QnA style"; and definitely not for rep farming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
val = '2013-01-09 06:13:51,464'.split(',')[0]  # Remove milliseconds
date_object = datetime.strptime(val, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to keep the microsecond?

```
>>> import re
>>> log = "2013-01-09 06:13:51,464 DEBUG module"
>>> p = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d*")
>>> time_str = p.findall(log)[0]
>>> time_str
'2013-01-09 06:13:51,464'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')
>>> date_time
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 6, 13, 51, 464000)
```

---

Comment: The use of regular expressions is redundant, if not overkill for this scenario.

Comment: ok. If the log format is not changed, `split` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "2013-01-09 06:13:51,464 DEBUG module"
>>> a = a.split(" ")
>>> date,time = a[0], a[1]
>>> date = date.split("-")
>>> time = time.split(",")[0].split(":")

>>> date
['2013', '01', '09']
>>> time
['06', '13', '51']


>>> args_list = [int(i) for i in date]
>>> args_list.extend( [int(i) for i in time])
>>> args_list
[2013, 1, 9, 6, 13, 51]

>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(*args_list)
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 6, 13, 51)
```

Comment: You're re-implementing the string parsing there which is already handled by the strptime function in the datetime class. Your answer is 4 times longer than mine. Also, why are you responding to your own question moments after asking it?